# jquery filtering - return div according it's data-id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery-filter

I'm trying to select every div with **class='selectthis'** and return their sibling divs *(also make them un-draggable)* if parent div's **data-id** not equals to **0**.

**Here is fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/umvQJ/1/

Here is my code:

```
<div class="selectthis" data-id="0">
     <div class='draggable'>don't return this</div>
</div>

<div class="selectthis" data-id="1">
     <div class='draggable'>return this</div>
</div>

<div class="selectthis" data-id="2">
     <div class='draggable'>return this</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.draggable').draggable();

    $(".selectthis").filter(function () { 
        return $(this[data-id!=="0"]).siblings(div); 
    }).draggable({revert: 'invalid'});
});
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that is what you need.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".selectthis").not('[data-id="0"]').find('.draggable').draggable();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/umvQJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".selectthis").filter(function () {
        return $(this).data('id') == 0
    }).siblings('div').draggable({
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/umvQJ/3/